Integrating TrustWalletCore in KMM Project: Issues with Swift Wrapper and Dependencies
Hello Stack Overflow community,
I'm currently working on a Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile (KMM) project and trying to integrate the TrustWalletCore library. I've encountered several issues, particularly with the iOS part of the integration.
My goal is to use TrustWalletCore for both Android and iOS. While the Android integration works fine, the iOS part is proving to be challenging. Specifically, I don't have access to all the functionalities of TrustWalletCore in Kotlin, so I decided to create a Swift wrapper class to expose the necessary methods.
KMM Setup: I have my KMM project set up with specific modules.
Here's my Podfile:
target 'iosApp' do
  use_frameworks!
  platform :ios, '14.1'
  pod 'wallet', :path => '../core/blockchain/wallet'
end

My build.gradle.kts module configuration:
  import org.gradle.nativeplatform.platform.internal.DefaultNativePlatform

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary)
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "17"
            }
        }
    }

    jvm("desktop")


    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "wallet"
            isStatic = true
        }
    }


    cocoapods {
        summary = "Some description for the Shared Module"
        homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
        version = "1.0"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "14.1"
        dependencies {
            pod("TrustWalletCore", moduleName = "WalletCore")
        }
        podfile = project.file("../../../iosApp/Podfile")
        framework {
            baseName = "wallet"
            listOf(
                iosX64(),
                iosArm64(),
                iosSimulatorArm64()
            ).forEach {
                it.binaries.all {
                    linkerOpts += "-ld64"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.koin.core)
                implementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization.json)
                implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.core)
               // implementation(libs.wallet.core)
                implementation("com.trustwallet:wallet-core-kotlin:+")
                implementation(projects.core.database)
                implementation(projects.core.common)
                implementation(projects.core.datastore)
                implementation(projects.core.model)
                implementation(projects.core.network)
                implementation(libs.bignum)
            }
        }

        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                // Add android specific dependencies if needed
            }
        }

        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting

        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
        }

        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.kotlin.test)
            }
        }

        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting

        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }

        val isArmMac = DefaultNativePlatform("test").architecture.isArm
        if (isArmMac) {
            iosSimulatorArm64()

            val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
            val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting

            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(iosMain)
            iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(iosTest)
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.cdcoding.wallet"
    compileSdk = 34
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
}

When I sync my project it completes successfully and in my code I can use the methods from core wallet. However, when I try to launch the application in my simulator, I get this error:

Ld
/Users/christophe/Documents/KMM/SecureWallet/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/SecureWallet.app/SecureWallet
normal (in target 'iosApp' from project 'iosApp')
cd /Users/christophe/Documents/KMM/SecureWallet/iosApp
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
-Xlinker -reproducible -target arm64-apple-ios15.3-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.5.sdk
-O0 -L/Users/christophe/Documents/KMM/SecureWallet/build/ios/EagerLinkingTBDs/Debug-iphonesimulator
-L/Users/christophe/Documents/KMM/SecureWallet/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator
-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator
-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.5.sdk/usr/lib/swift
-F/Users/christophe/Documents/KMM/SecureWallet/build/ios/EagerLinkingTBDs/Debug-iphonesimulator
-F/Users/christophe/Documents/KMM/SecureWallet/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator
-F/Users/christophe/Documents/KMM/SecureWallet/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftProtobuf
-F/Users/christophe/Documents/KMM/SecureWallet/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/TrustWalletCore
-F/Users/christophe/Documents/KMM/SecureWallet/iosApp/Pods/../../core/blockchain/wallet/build/cocoapods/framework
-F/Users/christophe/Documents/KMM/SecureWallet/iosApp/Pods/TrustWalletCore
-F/Users/christophe/Documents/KMM/SecureWallet/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TrustWalletCore/Core
-F/Users/christophe/Documents/KMM/SecureWallet/iosApp/../shared/build/xcode-frameworks/Debug/iphonesimulator17.5
-F/Users/christophe/Documents/KMM/SecureWallet/iosApp/../composeApp/build/xcode-frameworks/Debug/iphonesimulator17.5
-filelist /Users/christophe/Documents/KMM/SecureWallet/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SecureWallet.LinkFileList
-Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker
@loader_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker
/Users/christophe/Documents/KMM/SecureWallet/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SecureWallet_lto.o
-Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator
-L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/christophe/Documents/KMM/SecureWallet/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SecureWallet.swiftmodule
-ObjC -lc++ -framework SwiftProtobuf -framework WalletCore -framework wallet -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements
-Xlinker /Users/christophe/Documents/KMM/SecureWallet/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/SecureWallet.app-Simulated.xcent
-Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __ents_der -Xlinker /Users/christophe/Documents/KMM/SecureWallet/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/SecureWallet.app-Simulated.xcent.der
-framework Pods_iosApp -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/christophe/Documents/KMM/SecureWallet/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SecureWallet_dependency_info.dat
-o /Users/christophe/Documents/KMM/SecureWallet/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/SecureWallet.app/SecureWallet
ld: warning: search path
'/Users/christophe/Documents/KMM/SecureWallet/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftProtobuf'
not found ld: warning: search path
'/Users/christophe/Documents/KMM/SecureWallet/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/TrustWalletCore'
not found ld: warning: search path
'/Users/christophe/Documents/KMM/SecureWallet/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/TrustWalletCore/Core'
not found ld: warning: search path
'/Users/christophe/Documents/KMM/SecureWallet/iosApp/../shared/build/xcode-frameworks/Debug/iphonesimulator17.5'
not found ld: warning: search path
'/Users/christophe/Documents/KMM/SecureWallet/iosApp/../composeApp/build/xcode-frameworks/Debug/iphonesimulator17.5'
not found ld: framework 'SwiftProtobuf' not found

